# Is this antisymmetric? Why?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

This is from a past paper exam I am revising. Please can someone explain if this is antisymmetric or not. According to the answer it says it isn't, but I can't for the life of me understand why.

Consider the set N
+ of all non-empty finite sequences of natural numbers
– for example, [1, 1], [1, 2, 1] and [2, 0, 2, 0, 0] are all elements of N
+. Let R
be the binary relation over N
+ defined by (s, t) ∈ R if and only if s1 ≤ t1
where s1 and t1 are the first numbers of the sequences s and t, respectively.
For example, ([1, 1], [1, 2, 1]) ∈ R but ([2, 0, 2, 0, 0], [1, 1]) ∈/ R.

Answer (score 3):

It is not antisymmetric because, for instance, $[1\ \ 1]\mathrel R[1\ \ 2]$ and $[1\ \ 2]\mathrel R[1\ \ 1]$ , but you don't have $[1\ \ 1]=[1\ \ 2]$ .

Comment: Can you explain how [1  2] R [1  1] is a relation? I thought R was the less than or equal sign? If it is symmetric, how are they now equal?

Comment: We have $[1\ \ 2]\mathrel R[1\ \ 1]$ because the first element of $[1\ \ 2]$ (which is $1$) is smaller than or equal to the first element of $[1\ \ 1]$ (which is also $1$). I don't understand your other questions.